# Curve fitting with boundary conditions

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting, spline

I'm trying to fit a curve using LSQUnivariateSpline.

```
from scipy.interpolate import LSQUnivariateSpline, UnivariateSpline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 50)
y = np.exp(-x**2) + 0.1 * np.random.randn(50)

t = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
spl = LSQUnivariateSpline(x, y, t, k=4 )

xs = np.linspace(-3, 3, 1000)
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro', ms=5)
plt.plot(xs, spl(xs), 'g-', lw=3)
plt.show()
```

This code produce below graph.

[image]

I want to declare boundary conditions like dy/dx = 0 or d2x/dy = 0. Is there a way or another function to fit a curve with boundary conditions?

Comment: Are you trying to make a piecewise function where you use the LSQUnivariateSpline in the middle of the graph and change to some sort of linear function at the ends?

Comment: @Jack Moody Yes you are right. I want to add constraint at the beginning and end. At the end I want to get a piecewise polynomial with applied boundary conditions. x' = 0 or x" = 0.

Comment: I personally would fit the data to the equation using scipy's curve_fit(), do you have any particular reason for using a spline?

Comment: @James Philips I'm creating test data to compare the results of a system that creates piecewise polynomials as output.

Comment: In theory all splines have to deal with boundary conditions one or the other way. In case of `scipy.interpolate` you have underlying FORTRAN routines, though. To figure out, how it is done, you probably have to dig into those. On the other hand, if your case is not too general, you might try to program some spline fitting for yourself. It is not too complicated.